# Is it necessary to declare package name in java files if they belong to same folder?

Tags: java, class, package

I have a very simple java program. I only have 2 .java files located in the same folder. My question is... Do I have to explicitly declare in each file(or write package packageName; in each file) that they belong to the same package to be able to access the members of one another?

Comment: Just instantiate, or use directly to access static fields.. you don't need to do anything else.

Answer (score -1):

No you have to just declare the package name with * for import all files.
for eg. java.util.*;

You can have access all the files residing in the package util.